# in android making game which animation is better?

Tags: android, animation

I wanna make a game, just to practice the animations. I want to make jumping game means a player has to jump over the blocks and reach the highest position and if he fail he will die.
So please, i need some guide to sort the animation using it on Android

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: A smooth one. Btw so ist a qa page not a tutorial. So more info is needed. What surface you use and which animation do you mean.

Comment: i mean android provide three type of animations i.e frame , tweens, surface so which one is good to make game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using these [libraries](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/)

Add the jar to your project, or compile the source code. You have an example [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) and [tutorials](http://cocos2d.org/doc.html)

Next time please, work on the solution a bit more before asking it here, and explain your problem with more details.

Comment: i dnt wana stdy this i need the help to choose from follwing frame , tweens, surface

Comment: I like frames, because are easier to use. To use tweens and surface you need libraries that aren't in android yet